# generated jasper report is not showing bar chart

Tags: spring, jasper-reports, jfreechart

I have a report controller having code:

```
@Controller
public class ReportsController {


@RequestMapping(value="report.htm",method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public String showReport() throws JRException{

                ... 
                InputStream reportStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/report.jrxml");                

                JRDataSource dataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(reportData);

                HashMap params = new HashMap();
                params.put("Title", "Report");

                JasperDesign jd = JRXmlLoader.load(reportStream);


                JasperReport jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jd);

                JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, params, dataSource);

                JRHtmlExporter exporter = new JRHtmlExporter();

                exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jp);

                //EXPORTING REPORT TO A FILE "myreport.html"
                exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, "E:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 6.0/webapps/mywebapp/WEB-INF/jsps/reports/reportsOutput/myreport.html"); //--------statement (1)

                exporter.setParameter(JRHtmlExporterParameter.IS_USING_IMAGES_TO_ALIGN, false);
                exporter.setParameter(JRHtmlExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS, true);

                exporter.exportReport();

                return "report";
        }
}
```

In statement (1) I am exporting my generated report to a file **myreport.html**.

My report template file (**report.jrxml**) is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report5" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <field name="count" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="status" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <background>
        <band/>
    </background>
    <detail>
        <band height="343">
            <textField>
                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="8" y="14" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.Integer"><![CDATA[$F{count}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="267" y="14" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{status}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="146" y="14" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[status]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <barChart>
                <chart>
                    <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="108" y="119" width="200" height="100"/>
                    <chartTitle/>
                    <chartSubtitle/>
                    <chartLegend/>
                </chart>
                <categoryDataset>
                    <categorySeries>
                        <seriesExpression><![CDATA[""]]></seriesExpression>
                        <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{status}]]></categoryExpression>
                        <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{count}]]></valueExpression>
                        <itemHyperlink/>
                    </categorySeries>
                </categoryDataset>
                <barPlot>
                    <plot/>
                </barPlot>
            </barChart>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

**Problem** is that my generated report in `myreport.html` is showing everything *but does not show any bar chart*, instead showing blank white space in place of chart.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

Data to chart is provided by statement `JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, params, dataSource);` in the above code.

Moreover there is a folder generated, by jasper reports API, in the same dir in which there is my output file (myreport.html) lies  as:

/mywebapp/WEB-INF/jsps/reports/reportsOutput/**myreport.html** (Output file)

/mywebapp/WEB-INF/jsps/reports/reportsOutput/**myreport.html_files** (generated folder)

This generated folder (myreport.html_files) contains generated chart images according to template and are correct **but these chart images are not being shown up in the output file myreport.html** along with other text output of report.
Thanks...

Comment: Do you think that it is a spring/web container related problem? -- On in other words: have you tested is in a (Unit) Test?

Comment: @ralph: it is not a spring related problem. The problem relates to `exporting of jasper reports containing charts to a html file`. i labelled it as spring as i m using jasper reports in spring controller.

Comment: I just checked your report design and found that you aren't supplying any data to the chart component. How in the world, will the chart show up in the report, without any data being supplied to that? You need to setup the 'Chart Data' and also set the Axis MinValue and MaxValue expressions, for that to work.

Comment: @brightness : I'm talking about 'Chart Data', not the datasource. If you are using iReport, right-click on the chart component and check the 'Details' tab under 'Chart Data'.

Comment: @brightness: my exp. says there are issues with HTML export.
did u try to export it in other formats i.e. pdf or excel??
if not please check once.!

Comment: @indyaah: Yes there is some problem with html export as in folder myreport.html_files chart images are being generated properly according to data given by datasource BUT those images are getting insert into output file myreport.html. With pdf export it is working fine.

Comment: @aLearner: thats exactly what happended with me, i simply moved to pdf dropping html.!!!

Comment: @indyaah: After doing some R & D, i concluded that for images to get displayed on HTML output we have to configure some more things like IMAGE SERVLET (provided by jasper report) in web.xml and JASPERPRINT object in session etc. I m trying this solution, if get successful run, will print the solution here.

Comment: @aLearner: So, after your RD, have u discovered the solution for this problem? I have the same problem but I don't find the answer anywhere... Ah, and the ImageServlet resolved for my static image, but not for my dynamic ones. Thanks for ur (someone's) help.

Answer (score 0):

If there are bars of multiple colors, they will be displayed in a weaker and weaker shade. Export to PDF and you may see them