# how to export a jasper report with bar chart to a html file

Tags: jasper-reports

This question is in reference of [generated jasper report is not showing bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9096733/generated-jasper-report-is-not-showing-bar-chart)

I m exporting a report  built in jasper reports with bar chart (template report5.jrxml) to a html file.

Code:

```
    public showReport() throws JRException{

                    ... 
                    InputStream reportStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/report5.jrxml");                

                    JRDataSource dataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(reportData);

                    HashMap params = new HashMap();
                    params.put("Title", "Report");

                    JasperDesign jd = JRXmlLoader.load(reportStream);


                    JasperReport jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jd);

                    JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, params, dataSource);

                    JRHtmlExporter exporter = new JRHtmlExporter();

                    exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jp);

                    //EXPORTING REPORT TO A FILE "myreport.html"
                    exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, "E:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 6.0/webapps/mywebapp/WEB-INF/jsps/reports/reportsOutput/myreport.html"); 

                    exporter.setParameter(JRHtmlExporterParameter.IS_USING_IMAGES_TO_ALIGN, false);
exporter.setParameter(JRHtmlExporterParameter.IMAGES_DIR_NAME , "E:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 6.0/webapps/mywebapp/WEB-INF/jsps/reports/reportsOutput/myreport.html_files");                    exporter.setParameter(JRHtmlExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS, true);

                    exporter.exportReport();


            }
```

The generated report in output html file (myreport.html) shows text but does not show any chart.Though there is folder  (myreport.html_files) generated by jasper reports API next to the output file which contains chart images.

Why generated html is not showing any chart images?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9096733/generated-jasper-report-is-not-showing-bar-chart

Comment: @Alex K: yes, I have added a reference of that in this.